# In jqgrid, Is it possible to use select formatter without setting editoptions?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

Since one of my jqgrid column is not editable,so I do not set required value info i.e.{value:"1:John;2:Smith"} to editoptions, instead, I set formatter:select and value info to formatoptions. When I look at the js sourcecode of select formatter it tightly coupled with editoptions especially for getting "multiple" property of it. Is it possible to achieve this without writing custom formatter?

```
formatter:select
formatoptions:{value:"1:John;2:Smith"}
```

data being sent to this column is "1" or "2", and I expect from jqGrid to display John or Smith.

thanks,
Alper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, that the code of the [select formatter](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.2.0/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L346) could be improved to use `opts.colModel.formatoptions.multiple` in the line in the same way as it will be used `opts.colModel.editoptions.multiple` in [the line of code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.2.0/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L346).

Nevertheless I don't think that it's a real problem. If you has no `editable` property in the column or if you has `editable: false` the column stay non-editable even if you use `editoptions`.

So I agree you that the usage of `formatoptions.multiple` would be better, but I think that it's "nice to have" problem only.

Comment: well, yes in someway one can achieve to do the above case, but IMO for logical seperation this should be handled, otherwise it causes confusion. There are other cases in the source that may cause confusion such as "local","clientArray" concepts.Actually I changed the original formatter to handle it in agreed-way, cause  with the other sol'n I feel uncomfortable.